# Confguring Autoloader.php in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, xampp

```
require __DIR__.'require __DIR__.'/../public/vendor/autoloader.php';';
```

I have have tried to run this and i get the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Laravel\demo\public\index.php on line 27

Comment: The syntax highlighting from Stackoverflow should be sufficient to tell you what's wrong... `require __DIR__.'/../public/vendor/autoloader.php';`. Your path needs to be wrapped in quotes, and don't duplicate `require`.

Answer (score -1):

You've somehow managed to paste the `require` call into another copy of itself.

The entire line should simply be:

```
require __DIR__.'/../public/vendor/autoloader.php';
```